# IllegalStateException - Fragment.getResources

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

In my fragment, I am using resource strings at tons of places. 
Ideally, everything works fine.

But, I'm frequently getting crash reports for `IllegalStateException` saying Fragment is not attached to activity. 
One possible solution I can imagine is using `isAdded()` method which returns if fragment is attached to activity or not, but using this at all places before accessing string resource doesn't seem a correct solution to me, as it can break the flow.

Also, can I use following implementation, not sure if it is correct? 
Initialise `mActivity` on `onAttach` of fragment and then use it to get resource strings.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        mActivity = (Activity) context;
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
 getString(R.string.string_resource)
```

use

```
mActivity.getString(R.string.string_resource)
```

Can I be assured that using this will stop the `IllegalStateExceptions`?

Comment: Can you post the `Activity` and `Fragment` codes? Or the function where you get the error?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal entire activty and fragment code will be cumbersome, I'm getting this exception in onResponse method of retrofit request.

Comment: @MihirPatel please provide a stack trace of the `IllegalStateException` as well as the methods listed in this trace. It sounds like the issue is that you're performing some operations too early in the lifecycle (before `onAttach` has been called).

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 6):

> Can I be assured that using this will stop the IllegalStateExceptions?

No, definitely not. `Fragment.getString()` internally delegates to `requireContext().getResources()`, and `requireContext()` will only return a value while the `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`. So you'll really have the same issue, with more code.

Your issue is that you're calling `getString()` during an invalid part of the lifecycle. You mention that you're having this occur in a Retrofit response, so my assumption would be that you're submitting a network request within `Fragment`, and providing an anonymous response listener (which holds a reference to your `Fragment`). That request will continue even after the `Fragment` is detached, and then in your response listener you call `getString()`.

Consider moving to the [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/) (specifically [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)), and having your `ViewModel` perform the request, and post the result to a `LiveData` (which your `Fragment` can observe). That way you'll be guaranteed to only handle the result during a valid lifecycle state, and additionally the request will survive configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks @kcoppock. Can you please also share some references for architecture components you are referring to ?
It'll be really helpful.

Comment: Sure, I've added some inline links to the Arch components, ViewModel, and LiveData introductory docs.

Comment: I have these crashes in production Fragment `onActivityCreated()` methods which do nothing but call `getString()` (no background requests). I can't repro and don't know how to prevent - move everything that might use `getResources()` to `onResume()`?